# Credential In Windows

Tags: passwords, windows, credentials

How can I view the Credentials stored in Windows?

Is there any possible way to view the stored password?

I can just export them..

Comment: Do you mean all user account passwords, even ones you do not control?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager`and you'll see a list of locally saved password for windows. From there you can make a backup as well as add, delete and change entries.

Comment: You can't see the password there. It's just ******